# Google Chrome - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByClassName' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts

I have been trying to write my first user script for Google Chrome. It check the router page and reconnect until it gets a valid IP address.

I saved the script as IPchecker.user.js and installed it in google chrome via extensions page. But when I refresh the page, the javascript console throw an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByClassName' of null
```

From my understanding, this means that it does not know what document is. But how could this happen? I thought the script will be run AFTER the document has been ready? Is it not true? Here's the code which works in javascript console.

```
// ==UserScript==  
// @name         WAN checker
// @version      0.0.1
// @description  Check tomato IP addresses and reconnect as needed
// @match        *://192.168.1.1/status-overview.asp
// ==/UserScript== 

(function reconnect() {
    wan1ip = document.getElementById('wan1ip').getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerText.split('.').slice(0,2).join('.');

    if (wan1ip != "333.3333") {
    wan_connect("1");
    setTimeout("reconnect()",2000);
    }
    wan2ip = document.getElementById('wan2ip').getElementsByClassName('content')[0].innerText.split('.').slice(0,2).join('.');
if (wan2ip != "333.333") {
    wan_connect("2");
    setTimeout("reconnect()",2000);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling it on `document`. You're calling it on

```
 document.getElementById('wan1ip')
```

Make sure the element exists.

For testing, you can break it up and do

```
container = document.getElementById('wan1ip');
console.log(container, container.getElementsByClassName('content'));
```

That will show you what element you're doing `getElementsByClassName` on and then whatever elements of that class it finds in it. I bet the first one will be null.

This will also work but probably won't get you the result you're looking for:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('content')
```

Comment: Wow! Indeed. It's actually 'wanip' not 'wan1ip'. I have spent 2 hours not finding it. Thanks.